# jQuery client-side Insert, Update, Selete, Select data into database using template

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to develop client-side `select ,insert, update` and `delete` operation perform using `linq` to `sql` features of `.net`. Strictly I don't want to be using a server side coding. I have only using a client side coding.

Comment: Why do you want a pure client side solution .. any reason?

Comment: linq2sql is server side framework

Comment: yes but why do you seek a client side code to access the LinqToSql class?

Comment: it's possible using JSON but how i don't know. So if you have any link please give me.

Answer (score 0):

Linq-to-SQL is a server-side technology and so to be able to do your CRUD operations client-side, you will have to have *some* server-side code - it's purely unavoidable.

However, you can limit the amount you need to do by using [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668796%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). With this, you can expose an Entity Framework data context (*very* similar to Linq-to-SQL, in fact it's its successor) as a REST-like endpoint supporting JSON.

Take a look. It's very powerful and will allow you to spend as much of your time as possible in the client-side code.